# Comparar arquivo de texto com dados no banco

Tags: java, mysql

Bom dia, gostaria de saber como faço para comparar vários arquivos txt com o MySQL, para quando eu criar um arquivo txt na pasta ele não inserir novamente os dados dos outros arquivos txt na MySQL. Estou utilizando o JNotify para rodar em tempo real e inserir os dados do arquivo TXT no MySQL, toda vez que é inserido um arquivo txt na pasta.

Os dados do arquivo txt é "000040;034050500"
Cada txt há apenas uma informação dessa acima.

Segue meu código:

```
import net.contentobjects.jnotify.JNotify;
import net.contentobjects.jnotify.JNotifyListener;
import java.io.*;     
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;


public class Main {

      public static void main(String[] args) {

            try {
                  observarPasta();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                  e.printStackTrace();
            }
      }

      public static void observarPasta() throws Exception {

          // criei uma pasta temp para observar os arquivos que forem
          // criados e alterados dentro dela, mas pode ser alterado
          // para um arquivo especifico

          String path = "c:\\Users\\solutel\\Documents\\tabela\\";

          // a mask é as ações que vão ser observadas, mas pode
          // ser utilizado JNotify.FILE_ANY para monitorar tudo
          // também.

          int mask = JNotify.FILE_CREATED  |
                     JNotify.FILE_DELETED  |
                     JNotify.FILE_MODIFIED |
                     JNotify.FILE_RENAMED;

          // monitorar subPastas?
          boolean watchSubtree = true;

          // adiciona o "MONITORADOR"
          int watchID = JNotify.addWatch(path, mask, watchSubtree, new Listener());

          //Fica esperando um tempo até terminar a aplicação
          //Dependendo da implementação da sua aplicação
          //isso não será necessário mas para esse teste é interessante
          Thread.sleep(1000000);

          // aqui remove o seu "MONITORADOR"
          boolean res = JNotify.removeWatch(watchID);

          if (!res) {
            // o id foi inválido.
          }
        }

          //essa implementação ja se explica com seus métodos
        static class Listener implements JNotifyListener {
          public void fileRenamed(int wd, String rootPath, String oldName, String newName) {
            print("renomeado " + rootPath + " : " + oldName + " -> " + newName);
          }


          public void fileModified(int wd, String rootPath, String name) {
            print("modificado " + rootPath + " : " + name);   
          }

          public void fileDeleted(int wd, String rootPath, String name) {

            print("deletado " + rootPath + " : " + name);

          }

          public void fileCreated(int wd, String rootPath, String name) {

            print("criado " + rootPath + " : " + name);

            String dir = "C:\\Users\\solutel\\Documents\\tabela";
            File file = new File(dir);
            for(String arq : file.list()){           
            if(arq.endsWith(".txt")){

                try{
                    System.out.println(leitura(dir + "\\" + arq));
                }
                catch(Exception ex){}
            }
        }

        private static String leitura(String dir) throws Exception {


         Class.forName("org.gjt.mm.mysql.Driver");   
         Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/Radius","root","admin");   
         Statement stm = con.createStatement(); 

         BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File(dir)));

         String dados[] = new String[3]; 
         String linha = "", conteudo = "";  

         while((linha = reader.readLine()) != null){
            StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(linha,";\"");   
            dados[0] = st.nextToken();   
            dados[1] = st.nextToken();   
         }

            stm.executeUpdate("insert into radcheck (username,attribute,op,value) values ('"+dados[0]+"','" +"User-Password"+ "','"+ ":="+ "','"+dados[1]+"')");   
            linha = reader.readLine();            
            if(!linha.isEmpty()){
                conteudo = new StringBuilder(conteudo).append(linha.concat("\n")).toString();
            }


        reader.close();
        return conteudo;
    } 

          void print(String msg) {
            System.err.println(msg);
          }
        }
}
```

Comment: A forma mais simples que eu vejo é uma consulta ao valor antes de inseri-lo.

Comment: Como posso fazer isso? Pode me dar um exemplo? Obrigado